# iOS tabbar:Show tabbar items unselected

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

i am doing tabbar application having fourths.When i reached first view controller first tabitem is showing highlighted.And when i clicked the second tab second tabitem is highlighted .My problem is when i clicked the button in the second view other view appears for that also tabbaritem is highlighting.
So is there any solution for that not to highlighany tabbar item when such kind of buttons is clicked and for same thing of iussue happening in the navigation bar button also when i clicked

Comment: It sounds like like the other views are appearing in that tab are they not, similar to how the App Store app has tabs where you can load views in each tab.

Comment: Tabs must represent a part of the app, not a screen. If you just need shortcuts, you may use a menu instead.
You can also create your own component, starting with a toolbar